# How do I compare two columns with dates to see if they are exact as one seems to look like a date in the formula and the other a number

Tags: excel-2007

I need to compare a huge list of data which has two rows of dates as part of the whole data set. When I use the 'exact' formula, one looks like a date in the formula and the other a number and so they come up as not exact.

[image]

The response was helpful, though the data had been stored as dates. So I tried the suggestion , which did not help, but then tried `=IFERROR(DATEVALUE,F2=E2)` which worked for some of the data but not all,so still somewhat confused. It may be that the source data was provided to me in a strange way, so I'll need to follow up with the 'provder' of the initial data dump.

Answer (score 0):

The date in F2 is stored as text. You can do a comparison like this:

```
=DATEVALUE(F2)=E2
```